# Are convolution networks sensitive to the input features?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, feature-detection

How should I prepare input images for training in a **CNN** or any deep learning network? Do I have to prepare ***HOG*** or other filters alongside the original image? or just the images itself is enough?
I mean do I have to use threshold images as well or just the original image is sufficient?

Comment: This is always dependent on the task but the modern approaches are based on end-to-end learning where everything is done by the CNN byself (just feed it with standardized/normalized images). Thresholding for example will lose information and if needed could be approximately learned by the CNN too.

Comment: For object detection, is it necessary to separate each object one by one? Or can I use for example **HOG** and then a sliding window to detect objects in the original image?